# orchard localization ResourceManifest SetCultures override path pattern

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

In Orchard CMS I have following snipped

```
public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        var manifest = builder.Add();
        var currentCulture = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentCulture;

        manifest.DefineScript("jQuery-Validate-Localization").SetUrl("localization/messages.js").SetCultures(currentCulture);

    }
```

this will search for file "~/scripts/localization/messages.**en-US**.js" if current="en-US". Can I change pattern and path to become  "~/scripts/localization/messages**_en**.js"

How can I achieves this in ResourceManifest class?

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like following:

```
public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
{
    var manifest = builder.Add();
    var currentCulture = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentCulture;

    // split culture on '-' to get first part
    var url = "localization/messages_" + currentCulture.Split('-')[0] + ".js";

    manifest.DefineScript("jQuery-Validate-Localization").SetUrl(url);

}
```